# How do you find out your very first chat in a particular chatroom?

Tags: discussion, chat, chat-search

I want to know my very earliest/first chat post in a chatroom. Is there perhaps a way to search/view all my posts and sort the results?

Comment: Remember any words from the post? I think that's the only way short of digging through the transcripts

Comment: The best I can think of [was this](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/search?user=155407&room=10&q=hi).

Comment: @Richard Why did you delete that? Seemed to be working for me.

Comment: @Asad because it only helped for finding your first chat message overall, not for a particular room.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII That's OK. It's actually possible to identify from the href on the anchor in each message what room its from. It should be possible to cook up a user script that labels each message with the corresponding chat room.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It isn't documented, but using a bit of query param hacking, you can page through your chat entries, for example:

```
http://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/427309/richard-j-ross-iii?tab=recent&page=36
```

Just keep guessing larger and larger page numbers until you don't get any more results :)

It'd be nice to have an official way to page, though.

This doesn't truly answer the original question, but hopefully it points someone in the right direction.

Comment: Well, if there's no official way, this might be the best. It did help, thanks.

Comment: One never stop learning... this answer deserves more than meager 5 upvotes, will be fixed in 48 hours. :)

Answer (score 4):

The first thing you want to do is get to the "info"-page of the chatroom you want to get your first message from. As example: The Tavern on meta:

> [image: Info-Page for meta]

In the room-information panel you click on the <kbd>"Search for messages containing"</kbd>-Button. In the view showing up now you enter your username as demonstrated in following screenshot:

> [image: Searching the room]

Then you search for something that's in almost every message you ever write.. like `I`, order by newest, go to the last page you see, et voilà:

> [image: Search results when Searching for 'I']